# Using LGPL licensed library in LGPL project

Tags: jfreechart, lgpl

I am creating a project which uses [JFreeChart](http://jfree.org/jfreechart/) library which is licensed under LGPL. I am not modifying the original JFreeChart library. I intend to release this project under LGPL license. Can I do that? Also if yes then where is it mentioned in the LGPL License?

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it is about licensing or legal issues, not programming or software development. [See here](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/274963/questions-about-licensing/274964#274964) for details, and the [help] for more.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can. In fact, you can release your project under basically any license you want; LGPL was created to allow libraries to be released under an open-source license but still used in closed-source programs.

http://www.gnu.org/licenses/lgpl.html

> ### 3. Object Code Incorporating Material from Library Header Files.
>
> The object code form of an Application may incorporate material from a
>   header file that is part of the Library. You may convey such object
>   code under terms of your choice, provided that, if the incorporated
>   material is not limited to numerical parameters, data structure
>   layouts and accessors, or small macros, inline functions and templates
>   (ten or fewer lines in length), you do both of the following:
>
> a) Give prominent notice with each copy of the object code that the
>   Library is used in it and that the Library and its use are covered by
>   this License.
>
> b) Accompany the object code with a copy of the GNU GPL
>   and this license document.

---

> ### 4. Combined Works.
>
> You may convey a Combined Work under terms of
>   your choice that, taken together, effectively do not restrict
>   modification of the portions of the Library contained in the Combined
>   Work and reverse engineering for debugging such modifications, if you
>   also do each of the following:
>
> a) Give prominent notice with each copy of the Combined Work that the
>   Library is used in it and that the Library and its use are covered by
>   this License.
>
> b) Accompany the Combined Work with a copy of the GNU GPL and this
>   license document.
>
> c) For a Combined Work that displays copyright notices during
>   execution, include the copyright notice for the Library among these
>   notices, as well as a reference directing the user to the copies of
>   the GNU GPL and this license document.
>
> d) Do one of the following:
>
> > 0) Convey the Minimal Corresponding Source under the terms of this
> >     License, and the Corresponding Application Code in a form suitable
> >     for, and under terms that permit, the user to recombine or relink the
> >     Application with a modified version of the Linked Version to produce a
> >     modified Combined Work, in the manner specified by section 6 of the
> >     GNU GPL for conveying Corresponding Source.
> >
> > 1) Use a suitable shared library mechanism for linking with the
> >     Library. A suitable mechanism is one that (a) uses at run time a copy
> >     of the Library already present on the user's computer system, and (b)
> >     will operate properly with a modified version of the Library that is
> >     interface-compatible with the Linked Version.
>
> e) Provide Installation Information, but only if you would otherwise
>   be required to provide such information under section 6 of the GNU
>   GPL, and only to the extent that such information is necessary to
>   install and execute a modified version of the Combined Work produced
>   by recombining or relinking the Application with a modified version of
>   the Linked Version. (If you use option 4d0, the Installation
>   Information must accompany the Minimal Corresponding Source and
>   Corresponding Application Code. If you use option 4d1, you must
>   provide the Installation Information in the manner specified by
>   section 6 of the GNU GPL for conveying Corresponding Source.)

Comment: You cannot use LGPL licensed library inside Apache Licensed project. This link http://www.apache.org/legal/resolved.html#category-x explains it.

Also the license snippet shown is talking about GPL! If I am missing something I am really sorry because I am not a lawyer and can't even afford one!   ;)

Comment: @Naveen - go to the link. That is the actual text of the LGPL.

Comment: This link should be usefull in comparing compatibilities in various versions of GPL & LGPL. [How are the various GNU licenses compatible with each other?](http://www.gnu.org/licenses/gpl-faq.html#AllCompatibility)